# exporting plotted variable shows blank image

Tags: r, plot, jri

I am doing java and R integration using JRI.
Please find below script

```
            String path = "C:\\Users\\hrpatel\\Desktop\\CSVs\\DataNVOCT.csv";
            rengine.eval("library(tseries)");
            rengine.eval(String.format("mydata <- read.csv('%s')",path.replace('\\', '/')));
            String exportFilePath= "C:\\Users\\hrpatel\\Desktop\\CSVs\\arima3.jpg";
            rengine.eval("Y <- NewVisits");
            rengine.eval("t <- Day.Index");
            rengine.eval("summary(Y)");
            rengine.eval("adf.test(Y, alternative='stationary')");
            rengine.eval("adf.test(Y, alternative='stationary', k=0)");
            rengine.eval("acf(Y)");
            rengine.eval("pacf(Y)");
            rengine.eval("mydata.arima101 <- arima(Y,order=c(1,0,1))");
            rengine.eval("mydata.pred1 <- predict(mydata.arima101, n.ahead=1000)");
            rengine.eval(String.format("jpeg('%s')",exportFilePath.replace('\\', '/')));
            rengine.eval("plot(t,Y)");
            rengine.eval("lines(mydata.pred1$pred, col='blue',size=10)");
            rengine.eval("lines(mydata.pred1$pred+1*mydata.pred1$se, col='red')");
            rengine.eval("lines(mydata.pred1$pred-1*mydata.pred1$se, col='red')");
            rengine.eval("dev.off()");
```

In above codebase when i tried plot(t,Y) or plot(Y). it export a blank image, while in case of plot(mydata) it is working file.

One more thing when i run above code in R it creates the image(using JRI it shows blank image).

I have spend 1 day to solve this but i dont found any solution.

Please suggest if you have any alternatives.

Your help is needed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you have a data set named *mydata*, that has two columns, *NewVisits*, and *Day.Index*, in that case you need to change:

```
rengine.eval("Y <- NewVisits");
```

to

```
rengine.eval("Y <- mydata$NewVisits");
```

and

```
rengine.eval("t <- Day.Index");
```

to

```
rengine.eval("t <- mydata$Day.Index");
```

This also explains why *plot(mydata)* works for you - because R recognizes it.

if this isn't the solution, then i cant see where you are reading *NewVisits* and *Day.Index* from

BTW i stongly recommend to plot using the  `ggplot` package

Comment: Do you have any idea to integrate google analytics in java and download its data. i already have tried the same using appengine project but there is restriction to download File data as appengine has restricted FileWriter APi.

Comment: There is a google analitics package in r you might want to use it